# 2D cutout object transparency

Tags: transparency, 2d

**EDIT 2:**
I realized with cycles on it almost works as suggested but I only get a "shadowed" version of the tree to control tranparency:

[image]

Do you know how to make it so it shows the original color version, not just the mask? I've tried using the original alpha channel as well as creating a seperate mask png, but neither seems to work.

Comment: if you need to add additional transparency, you need to mix your first Mix Shader into a second one, with a Transparent shader in the other socket, and a texture into the factor, that will determine which part is transparent

Comment: but please try to elaborate when you say "to be able to ghost the tree out and see something behind it", because it will also depend on what you mean by that

Comment: Thanks for your quick response moonboots! I've tried your suggestion (as best I unsterstand) but still can't get it to work. I've edited the original post with additional information so you understand what I'm looking to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: you need to determine what will be the parts that will be transparents, and create a mask, a b&w picture that will make parts transparent and other opaques, then you plug this mask in the Factor of the second Mix shader

Comment: I created a black mask of just the tree (which I want to make transparent), but when I plug the color output into the second shader Fac, it doesn't do anything, and if I put the alpha into it, I only get the black shadow as shown in my latest edit.